# How to implement ON ( ... OR ...) mysql query in doctrine2 queryBuilder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a SQL query in MYSQL:
For example

```
SELECT s.* FROM vplanning.cities as c1
INNER JOIN vplanning.cities as c2
ON (c1.id = c2.area_id)
INNER JOIN vplanning.storages as s
ON (s.city_id = c2.id OR s.city_id = c1.id)
WHERE c1.id = 109;
```

In doctrine I can write something like this (from my work code):

```
$query = $em->getRepository('VplanningPageBundle:Storage')
            ->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->innerJoin('s.city', 'c1')
            ->innerJoin('c1.area', 'c2')
            ->innerJoin('s.storagestype', 'st')
            ->where('c2.id = :cityID')
            ->andWhere('st.typename = :storagesTypeName')
            ->andWhere('s.active = :active')
            ->setParameters(array(
                'cityID' => $cityID,
                'storagesTypeName' => $storagesTypeName,
                'active' => 1
            ))
            ->orderBy('s.adress')
            ->getQuery();
```

As you can see, I show my relation in

```
->innerJoin('s.city', 'c1')
```

but I need also relation like

```
->innerJoin('s.city', 'c2')
```

with this condition:

```
ON (s.city_id = c2.id OR s.city_id = c1.id)
```

But it throws this error:

> Error: 'c2' is already defined

`c1` and `c2` are the same entity and have a inner relation.

Comment: I think better choice would be using [NativeSql](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)..

Comment: I thought about this way, it seems the only right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem was very difficult as for me, I have to study it :)

This is a answer for my question from some forum board:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('VplanningPageBundle:Storage')->createQueryBuilder('storage');
            $query = $qb->join('storage.city', 'city1', Join::WITH)
                ->leftJoin('city1.area', 'area', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('area.id', ':cityID'))
                ->leftJoin('storage.city', 'city2', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('city2.id', ':cityID'))
                ->join('storage.storagestype', 'type', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('type.typename', ':storagesTypeName'))
                ->where('storage.active = :active')
                ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX($qb->expr()->isNotNull('city2'), $qb->expr()->isNotNull('area')))
                ->setParameters(array(
                'cityID' => $cityID,
                'storagesTypeName' => $storagesTypeName,
                'active' => 1
            ))
                ->orderBy('storage.adress')
            ->getQuery();
```

Comment: But this actually is more complex sql request, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('VplanningPageBundle:Storage');
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('storage');
//We can now use the expr()
$qb->join('storage.city', 'city', Join::WITH)
   ->join('city.area', 'area', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('area.id', ':cityID'))
   ->join('storage.storagestype', 'type', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('type.typename', ':storagesTypeName'))
   ->where('storage.active = :active')
   ->setParameters(array(
       'cityID' => $cityID,
       'storagesTypeName' => $storagesTypeName,
       'active' => 1
   ))
   ->orderBy('storage.adress');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: I have the same result what I had before, but your code is something new for me, I'll play with him. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try smth like this

```
$qb = $this->getRepository('VplanningPageBundle:City')->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->leftJoin('c.area', 'a')
    ->join('c.storage', 's', Join::ON, $qb->expr()->orX($qb->expr()->eq('c.id', 's.id'), $qb->expr()->eq('a.id', 's.id')))
    ->innerJoin('s.storagestype', 'st')
    ->where('c.id = :cityID')
    ->andWhere('st.typename = :storagesTypeName')
    ->andWhere('s.active = :active')
    ->setParameters(array(
       'cityID' => $cityID,
       'storagesTypeName' => $storagesTypeName,
       'active' => 1,
    ))
    ->orderBy('s.adress')
    ->getQuery()
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's throws a `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 92: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'`, but I think you gave me an idea, it's time to read docs :)